# How to index into a django model's attribute?

Tags: django, database, indexing, blogs

I am making a blog and have a model for an article:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title       = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author      = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    content     = models.TextField(db_index=True)
    committee   = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    likes       = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I am working on a method of truncating posts and need to access the first few characters of the content attribute. I tried {{article.content[40]}} (article has been passed in as context in my view function) but that threw this error:

Could not parse the remainder: '[0:40]' from 'article.content[0:40]'

Does anyone know how to index into an attribute like this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this

`

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title       = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author      = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    content     = models.TextField(db_index=True)
    committee   = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    likes       = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    get_content(self):
        return self.content[:40]
```

`

Then in your template

```
{{article.get_content}}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this a shot!

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the [**`|slice`** template filter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#slice):

```
{{ article.content|slice:":40" }}
```

It might however be better to make use of the [**`|trucatechars`** template filter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatechars):

> Truncates a string if it is longer than the specified number of characters. Truncated strings will **end with a translatable ellipsis** character (`"…"`).

This will thus add an ellipsis (…) at the end of the string if has been truncated, you thus can use this with:

```
{{ article.content|truncatechars:40 }}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep this in mind going forward!